# Add image to LibreOffice Writer 7 "Application Background"

Tags: libreoffice

I'm wondering if it is possible to set an image to the LibreOffice Writer "Application Background". This is the area in blue the attached image. I can modify the color of this area by going to tools -> options -> Application colors -> Application background but I'm not seeing an option to use an image rather than a solid color. Is this possible? I'm using LibreOffice Writer 7.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not in the place where you set the background color, it's very unlikely you can set it elsewhere.

Looking at libreoffice in general, I can't remember any place you could do the kind of customization you want.

Remembering a bit of the source code needed to scroll pages, having the background be some solid color makes things a lot easier; so, unless that code has changed in the last 15 years or so, I'm afraid what you want is impossible.